# Use phalcon classes in base controller rather than on individual controllers

Tags: php, phalcon

I have a base controller as follows

```
<?php
use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class ControllerBase extends Controller {


    public function initialize() {

    }

    // wrapper function for debug purposes.
    public function pr($data = null) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($data);
        echo '</pre>';      
    }

}
```

and a users controller as follows

```
<?php
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Criteria;
use Phalcon\Paginator\Adapter\Model as Paginator;
use Phalcon\Mvc\View;

class UsersController extends ControllerBase {


    public function initialize() {
        // initialize parent, here ControllerBase.
        parent::initialize();
    }

    public function loginAction() {

        // disable the main layout.
        $this->view->disableLevel(View::LEVEL_MAIN_LAYOUT);
        // disable the controller layout.
        $this->view->disableLevel(View::LEVEL_LAYOUT);
    }
        .
        .
        .
        .
        other functions...


}
```

i was wondering if i could call all the required phalcon classes in base controller and extend then to all the child classes so that i dont need to call them individually on each controller.

in otherwords, can i add the below code

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Criteria;
use Phalcon\Paginator\Adapter\Model as Paginator;
use Phalcon\Mvc\View;
```

only in the base controller and acces them in other controllers. I tried putting them base controller but it gave error : Class not found.

Is this the right way or is there something wrong in my approach...please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly the answer is NO.

[Namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php) are language feature and works this way. The `use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Criteria` only declares that you'll use `Criteria` class from `Phalcon\Mvc\Model\` namespace. So in your code you can write `new Criteria()` to create object instead of using its' full name `new \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Criteria()`.

You must declare each class in every file which instantiates object of that class so [autoloader](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/loader.html) will know in which file given class exists.

Comment: Thankz for the clarification and the link, it was very helpful....i will do it that way....